# How Do I make an Iframe go to a random page every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need help with an iframe.

So far, I have this code set up

```html
<iframe height="300px" width="100%" src="/vite" name="iframe_a"></iframe>

<button><a href="/multi" target="iframe_a">MULTI</a></button>
<button><a href="/facebook" target="iframe_a">Facebook</a></button>
```

However, I don't want the buttons. I want the iframe to redirect in order of a list of web pages every five seconds because:
Next to it, I have a slideshow, and when its logo appears, I would like the frame to redirect to the page of which the logo is indicating.

Example:

> Facebook logo > href="/facebook"
>   [5 seconds later]
>   Vite logo > href="/vite"
>   [5 seconds later]
>   MULTI logo > href="/multi"

I already have the slideshow setup, just asking for the frame.

Thanks heaps

Comment: You've got some code (which you haven't bothered to put in the question) that changes the slide show. Change that code so it also changes the frame at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. Note: The websites you use must include the correct iframe and origin headers (or be served from the same domain as the parent site) to display inside your iframe

```js
//Array of URLs for the iframe to cycle through
var websites=["https://wikipedia.org","https://stackoverflow.com","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497495/how-do-i-make-an-iframe-go-to-a-random-page-every-5-secounds#"], 
//Variable to hold the iframe node reference
iframe, 
//Time to show each website in milliseconds
INTERVAL=5000, 
//Variable to keep track of currentSlide being shown
currentSlide=-1;

//Method to update the SRC attribute of iframe
function switchSlides(){
  currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%websites.length;
  iframe.src = websites[currentSlide];
}

//Wait for document to load
window.onload=function(){
  //Get iframe reference
  iframe = document.getElementById("slides");
  //Use setInterval to set up repeating task of switching slides
  setInterval(switchSlides,INTERVAL)
}
```

```html
<iframe id="slides" height="300px" width="100%" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

Comment: What about if it is not secure? how to I get it to work if it is not secure?

Comment: If you are testing from the code snippet above (which is served from https) you will need to use https sites. But if your site is not https you can use other sites without http

Comment: Your code above works but my sites are not https (secure) they are http. How do I get the code above to work with http instead?