# How to get Javascript to run on http websites instead of https

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497495/how-do-i-make-an-iframe-go-to-a-random-page-every-5-seconds), [Chirag Ravindra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649853/chirag-ravindra) helped me out with the code here.

```js
//Array of URLs for the iframe to cycle through
var websites=["https://wikipedia.org","https://stackoverflow.com","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497495/how-do-i-make-an-iframe-go-to-a-random-page-every-5-secounds#"], 
//Variable to hold the iframe node reference
iframe, 
//Time to show each website in milliseconds
INTERVAL=5000, 
//Variable to keep track of currentSlide being shown
currentSlide=-1;

//Method to update the SRC attribute of iframe
function switchSlides(){
  currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%websites.length;
  iframe.src = websites[currentSlide];
}

//Wait for document to load
window.onload=function(){
  //Get iframe reference
  iframe = document.getElementById("slides");
  //Use setInterval to set up repeating task of switching slides
  setInterval(switchSlides,INTERVAL)
}
```

```html
<iframe id="slides" height="300px" width="100%" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

It is a great code, however, I can only use it for secure sites (https). My sites do not have https. How do I make the code run on http instead of https?

What the code does is makes an iframe change every 5 seconds. Below where it says

```js
//Array of URLs for the iframe to cycle through
```

runs only https sites. I am asking how to run http sites or even pages on current site (/about or something like that)
Thanks heaps!

Comment: Make sure the site opens on http networks. If it does, just append http/https according to your array strings.

Comment: I assume you are calling the document that contains this script itself via HTTPS? Then browsers will block your attempt to embed external resources that are not requested via HTTPS themselves, but via HTTP only, as “insecure content”. If you want to be able to do this with sites that are available via HTTP only - then you must first of all call your document via just HTTP as well.

Comment: I try your code and I get it worked by just calling a http website for example: http://www.theuselessweb.com/.      Make sure that you are changing "https" for "http" in the websites var..